# How to make a for loop either increasing or decreasing?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have to loop between two values where sometimes the first value is less than the second, and some other times the first is greater than the second (I'm working on two cells inside a grid and the first cell can be on the left of the second or vice versa).

With Python, I can specify if a for loop has to decrease or to increase its values, but the result is something like that:

```
step = 1
if y < x:
    step = -1
for n in range(x, y, step):
    pass
```

Is there something more *"pythonic"* to obtain this?

Comment: You could just do: `for n in range(x, y, -1 if y < x else 1):`. It's essentially the same as your code

Comment: Note that using step as `-1` is not the same as looping from the smaller to the greater value!

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for highlighting it: you spotted a bug in my code! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that using `step=-1` is *not* the same as a range from the smaller to the larger value!

```
>>> range(3, 7, 1)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> range(7, 3, -1)
[7, 6, 5, 4]
```

The first one is from 3 to 6, the latter one from 4 to 7.

If that's still what you want, another way would be to use `or`:

```
>>> x, y = 7, 3
>>> range(x, y, x < y or -1)
[7, 6, 5, 4]
```

If you want to include both the lower and upper index, you have to offset the `to` index:

```
>>> step = +1 if x < y else -1 # or use that 'or' expression
>>> range(x, y + step, step)
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

Otherwise, you could sort the values first, either using `min` and `max` or `sorted`:

```
>>> x, y = sorted((x, y))
>>> range(x, y)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or in one line: `range(*sorted((x, y)))` (although I don't think this is very readable)

---

I did some timing analysis, ordering 1000 random `x, y` pairs (same pairs for each method):

- `x, y = sorted((x, y))` -> ~305µs for 1000 pairs
- `x, y = min(x, y), max(x, y)` -> ~235µs for 1000 pairs
- `x, y = (x, y) if x < y else (y, x)` -> ~75µs for 1000 pairs

So the ternary operator is the fastest, but in most cases it probably should not matter much, compared to the rest of the code (creating the range etc.)

Comment: You could use `range(*((x, y) if x < y else (y, x)))` instead of calling the `sorted()` function.

Comment: @martineau Ah, yes, that's another possibility besides sorted and min/max. Not easy to decide which is the least horrible... IMHO it's a bit harder to understand/parse, but from a performance-perspective, yours is probably the fastest, but this should only be relevant if this is executed really really often.

Comment: `sorted()` is definitely the most readable and probably just fine 99.9% of the time. It's my background in C that leads me to think in terms of ternary expressions to avoid calling a function just to sort two items.

Comment: @martineau I agree with you; I use this for loop a lot of times and I'd prefer not to call a function, since python doesn't support inlining (I cannot use PyPy).

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
for n in xrange(min(x,y), max(x,y)):
```

Your way is already pretty much pythonic ;)

Edit: Shorter way suggest by @wap26:

```
for n in xrange(*sorted((x,y))):
```

Comment: The set of indexes is correct, but the direction is always increasing order.

Comment: Slightly more compact : `xrange(*sorted((x,y)))`

Comment: I will amend the unclear question. `I have to loop between two values where sometimes the first value is lesser that the second and some other times the first is greater than the second`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't do much different to your code, but you could use this to calculate the `step`

```
range(x,y,(y-x)/abs(x-y))
```

For example:

```
In [10]: x,y = 5,10

In [11]: range(x,y,(y-x)/abs(x-y))
Out[11]: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [12]: x,y = 10,5

In [13]: range(x,y,(y-x)/abs(x-y))
Out[13]: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
```